# css variable not working in email from google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a reason that css variables are not working? Is there a css version issue for Google apps script?

I am sending an email through Google apps script with html like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      :root {
        --blue: #1e90ff;
        --white: #ffffff;
      }

      body { background-color: var(--blue); }

      h2 { border-bottom: 2px solid var(--blue); }

      .container {
        color: var(--blue);
        background-color: var(--white);
        padding: 15px;
      }

      button {
        background-color: var(--white);
        color: var(--blue);
        border: 1px solid var(--blue);
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>this is H2</h2>
    <button>this is button</button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

using [example from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)

and the result shows no mapping of the CSS variables:

[image: regular H2 and unformatted button]

the apps script code is like:

```
let template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test");
let htmlMessage = template.evaluate().getContent()
  
GmailApp.sendEmail(email@email.com, 
                    "Auto Response", 
                    "Your email doesn't support html",
                    {bcc: "bcc@bcc.com", name: "Name", 
                    htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: "email@email.com"})
```

Comment: fyi: the answer is it doesn't work with email but it does work with a modeless dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it this way:

```
function showasimpledialog() {
  const html=' <!DOCTYPE html><html>  <head>    <base target="_top">    <style>      :root {        --blue: #1e90ff;        --white: #ffffff;      }      body { background-color: var(--blue); }      h2 { border-bottom: 2px solid var(--blue); }      .container {        color: var(--blue);        background-color: var(--white);        padding: 15px;      }      button {        background-color: var(--white);        color: var(--blue);        border: 1px solid var(--blue);        padding: 5px;      }    </style>  </head>  <body>    <h2>this is H2</h2>    <button>this is button</button>      </body></html>';

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Title');
}
```

Output:

[image]

It renders okay in a dialog.

Comment: thanks. maybe it's just a problem for email.

Comment: May be.  I'll give it a try in email

Comment: I tried it with and without variables and evidently it doesn't support variables.